# CustomTkinter giving error after destroy a window

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I have a window in `customtkinter`, version `5.20`, with a button to destroy it:

```
import customtkinter as ctk

# window 1
window1 = ctk.CTk()
window1.geometry('400x300')

ctk.CTkButton(window1, text = 'Destroy', command = window1.destroy).pack(expand = True)

window1.mainloop()
```

The code works fine as it should be, but if after destroy the window I want to create a second one:

```
# window 2
window2 = ctk.CTk()
window2.geometry('400x300')
window2.mainloop()
```

Then the code give me this error:

```
invalid command name "2036367448128update"
    while executing
"2036367448128update"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "2036367449792check_dpi_scaling"
    while executing
"2036367449792check_dpi_scaling"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "2036367445824_click_animation"
    while executing
"2036367445824_click_animation"
    ("after" script)
```

The code works and the second window is created, but I don't get what this error means.

I tried to write this in `Tkinter` and it doesn't give me any error:

```
import tkinter as tk

# window 1
window1 = tk.Tk()
window1.geometry('400x300')

tk.Button(window1, text = 'Destroy', command = window1.destroy).pack(expand = True)

window1.mainloop()

# window 2
window2 = tk.Tk()
window2.geometry('400x300')
window2.mainloop()
```

I also tried to use `quit()` instead of `destroy()`, but the first window is not closed and just create the second one.

Comment: Should be `window2 = tk.Toplevel()` instead of `window2 = tk.Tk()`

Comment: @toyotaSupra it gives me more errors than before, anyway I simply resolved it by using `tkinter` for `window1` and `customtkinter` for `window2`

Comment: # window 2
window2 = ctk.CTkToplevel()
window2.geometry('400x300')

Comment: Comment out `window2.mainloop()`